# Request filter versus request interceptor?

Tags: spring, rest, filter, jersey, interceptor

My application exposes a RESTful API which when called calls out to a mailbox server and fetches data. I want to be able disable the service during application runtime in the event of some outage on the mailbox server. I wanted to do this in a way that the logic of deciding whether or not to call the mailbox server was abstracted from the actual code that calls the mailbox server. Two options which seem to fit this scenario are filters and interceptors however I'm looking for advice on which one best suits this requirement and what are the difference between each?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring MVC then you can use an interceptor, which is like a filter but that has access to the Spring context. If you are using Jersey then you can't use interceptors.

Comment: The above is not true anymore. JAX-RS 2.0 has filters and interceptors. Jersey 2 is nearing production release.